# Gerar chave sequencial com base na soma dos dígitos

Tags: c#, .net

> Possuo função cíclica onde uma *string* inicial pode ter qualquer valor no dígito verificador, porém todas as futuras submissões recebem um valor previamente calculado.

Nesta função, eu recebo uma `string` (que será sempre um número) e neste método, retiro o último dígito e faço a somatória do restante. No final, retorno esse número + 1 e concateno com a somatória. Complicado dessa forma que expliquei, não?

Explicando melhor, seria isso:
recebo a string 10000 e o retorno deverá ser 10011. Onde o 1000 somou + 1 e o próximo último dígito é a soma dos restantes (1 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 1).

Meu método está da seguinte forma:

```
public static int GenerateKey(string s)
        {           
            s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1);

            var i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
            var sum = 0;

            while (i != 0)
            {
                sum += i % 10;
                i /= 10;
            }

            var somatorio = Convert.ToInt32(s) + 1;

            var id = Convert.ToString(somatorio);

            if (sum.ToString().Length > 1)
            {
                sum = sum % 10;
            }

            id = id += sum;

            return Convert.ToInt32(id);
        }
```

**1º:** Este método precisa de melhorias e/ou está "mal escrito"?

**2º:** Utilizando esse método é possível que o retorno seja repetido com um já utilizado antes? **Lembrando que a próxima vez que executar o método o número será o return do método executado anteriormente.**

Ex: se em comecei com 10000, o retorno será 10011 então a próxima vez que o método for executado a *string* terá o valor de 10011, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mal escrito não está (na minha opinião), eu mudaria alguns pequenos detalhes, mas é cosmético:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(GenerateKey("10000"));
        WriteLine(GenerateKey("10011"));
        WriteLine(GenerateKey("10100"));
        WriteLine(GenerateKey("00000"));
        WriteLine(GenerateKey("999999999"));
    }
    public static int GenerateKey(string s) {           
        s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
        var i = ToInt32(s);
        var sum = 0;
        while (i != 0) {
            sum += i % 10;
            i /= 10;
        }
        var somatorio = ToInt32(s) + 1;
        var id = somatorio.ToString();
        if (sum.ToString().Length > 1) {
            sum %= 10;
        }
        id += sum;
        return ToInt32(id);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R8Am0y). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jeWiPh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/GenerateSequetialKey.cs).

Não analisei profundamente se há algum erro, mas parece que não. A linha `id = id += sum;` não chega causar erro neste caso, mas é bem estranho fazer isto.

Não posso te provar matematicamente mas parece que não vai repetir em condições normais. Claro que precisaria ver o que acontece quando há inconsistência no número, se ele for grande demais. Talvez você possa garantir que isto não ocorra em outra lugar do código ou tenha total controle dos dados usados. Pensou no que pode acontecer se mandar um "00000"? Ou um "0"? Ou um "99999"? OU "999999999"? Ou "9999999999"?

Obviamente não posso garantir se faz o que deseja. Parece um algoritmo estranho, mas deve ter um motivo para ele existir.

Comment: Esses números que você comentou são tratados antes. Meu medo mesmo era que eu poderia ter algum problema (que eu não vi). Esse algoritmo foi pedido pelos nossos técnicos, para atender à uma customização. Eu particularmente acho uma "gambiarra" para a funcionalidade proposta, mas isso não vem ao caso.
Muito obrigado pela resposta.